# Moving multiple files with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, move, gsutil

Let's say I've got the following files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket:

```
file_A1.csv
file_B2.csv
file_C3.csv
```

Now I want to move a subset of these files, lets say `file_A1.csv` and `file_B2.csv`. Currently I do this like that:

```
gsutil mv gs://bucket/file_A1.csv gs://bucket/file_A11.csv
gsutil mv gs://bucket/file_B2.csv gs://bucket/file_B22.csv
```

This approach requires two call of more or less the same command and moves each file separately. I know, that if I move a complete directory I can add the `-m` option in order to accelerate this process. However, unfortunately I just want to move a subset of all files and keep the rest untouched in the bucket.

When moving 100 files this way I need to execute 100 commands or so and this becomes quite time consuming. I there a way to combine each of the 100 files into just one command with addtionally the `-m` option?

Comment: Do you have a rule for what the destination's name is? Is that also in a file, or is it "repeat the last letter of the existing file", or something more elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gsutil does not support this currently but what you could do is create a number of shell scripts, each performing a portion of the moves, and run them concurrently.

Note that [gsutil mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) is based on the syntax of the [unix mv command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv), which also doesn't support the feature you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought about that. However, is there a limit of concurrent commands that are allowed to be executed simultaneously?

Comment: Only normal operating system limitations would apply; the tool itself can be executed any number of times concurrently.

Comment: Okay, I wrote a small script that move 100 files in parallel. The result was that just 25 files were moved and the whole process took 10 minutes. Defintely not a solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a list of the files you want to move you can use the [`-I` option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) from the `cp` command which, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#options), is also valid for the `mv` command:

```
cat filelist | gsutil -m mv -I gs://my-bucket
```

Comment: that's what I came here for!

Answer (score 7):

That worked for me for moving all txt files from **gs://config** to **gs://config/new_folder**

```
gsutil mv 'gs://config/*.txt' gs://config/new_folder/
```

[I had some problems using the wildcard * in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083114/3335606), so that is the reason for the  quotes around the origin path

Comment: works perfectly in the cloud console shell as well +1

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve that using bash by iterating over the `gsutil ls` output for example:

- source folder name: `old_folder`
- new folder name: `new_folder`

```
for x in `gsutil ls "gs://<bucket_name>/old_folder"`; do y=$(basename -- "$x");gsutil mv ${x} gs://<bucket_name>/new_folder/${y}; done
```

you can run in parallel if you have a huge number of files using:

```
N=8 # number of parallel workers
(
for x in `gsutil ls "gs://<bucket_name>/old_folder"`; do 
   ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
   y=$(basename -- "$x");gsutil mv ${x} gs://<bucket_name>/new_folder/${y} & 
done
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not documented widely but this works all the time

To move the contents of the third folder to the root or any folder before it

```
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/first/second/third/ | gsutil -m mv -I gs://my-bucket/first/
```

and to copy

```
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/first/second/third/ | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket/first/
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can run the follow gsutil command:

```
gsutil mv gs://bucket_name/common_file_name*  gs://bucket_destiny_name/common_file_name*
```

In your case; common_file_name is "file_"

Answer (score 0):

The lack of `-m` flag is the real hang up here.  Facing the same issue I originally managed this by using python multiprocessing and `os.system` to call gsutil.  I had 60k files and it was going to take hours. With some experimenting I found using the python client gave a 20x speed-up!

If you are willing to move away from `gsutil` - its a better approach.

Here is a copy(or move) method.  If you create a list of src keys/uri's you can call this using multi-threading for fast results.

Note: the method a tuple of (destination-name,exception) which you can pop into a dataframe or something to look for failures

```
def cp_blob(key=None,bucket=BUCKET_NAME,uri=None,delete_src=False):
    try:
        if uri:
            uri=re.sub('gs://','',uri)
            bucket,key=uri.split('/',maxsplit=1)
        client=storage.Client()
        bucket=client.get_bucket(bucket)
        blob=bucket.blob(key)
        dest=re.sub(THING1,THING2,blob.name)  ## OR SOME OTHER WAY TO GET NEW DESTINATIONS
        out=bucket.copy_blob(blob,bucket,dest)
        if delete_src:
            blob.delete()
        return out.name, None
    except Exception as e:
        return None, str(e)
```