# Zsh error when trying to run tensorflow model training script

Tags: python, tensorflow, scripting, command-line-arguments, zsh

I am trying to train a resnet model for CIFAR10 using the following repo in tensorflow: https://github.com/stanford-futuredata/dawn-bench-models/tree/master/tensorflow/CIFAR10/resnet. Even though the readme mentions tensorflow 1.2, I got a `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2` when trying to install, so I am instead using tensorflow 1.15. I am also using Python 3.7.6 and running on a Mac. When I try to run the training script `resnet_main.py`:

```
python3 resnet/resnet_main.py --train_data_path=cifar10/data_batch* \
                            --log_root=/tmp/resnet_model \
                            --train_dir=/tmp/resnet_model/train \
                            --dataset='cifar10'
```

I get the following command line error: `zsh: no matches found: --train_data_path=cifar10/data_batch*`. I imagine it has to do with the `*`, though I'm not sure, and I'm not sure what the work around is. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gsutil returning "no matches found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075182/gsutil-returning-no-matches-found)

Comment: Yes, adding single quotes helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as simple as adding single quotes, such as `--train_data_path='cifar10/data_batch*'`, for all the filepaths.